# Trying to create a column with the maximum timestamp in PySpark DataFrame

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am really new to PySpark. All I want to do is to find the maximum of the "date" column and add a new column in the dataframe that has this maximum date for all the rows (repeating) such that:

```
A      B                                        C
a  timestamp1                              timestamp3
b  timestamp2    -------------------->     timestamp3
c  timestamp3                              timestamp3
```

I use the following line of code:

```
df.withColumn('dummy_column',f.lit((f.max('date'))).cast('timestamp')).show(9)
```

But I get the error:

```
> AnalysisException: grouping expressions sequence is empty, and
> '`part`' is not an aggregate function. Wrap '(CAST(max(`date`) AS
> TIMESTAMP) AS `new_column`)' in windowing function(s) or wrap '`part`'
> in first() (or first_value) if you don't care which value you get.;;
```

Can anyone help me understand why do I get this error and how can I work around it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably looking for:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

w = Window.rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.unboundedFollowing)
df.withColumn('dummy_column',f.max('date').over(w).cast('timestamp')).show(9)
```

Aggregate functions like `max` work with a window or a grouping operation. They cannot work on their own because you did not specify the range of rows over which the aggregate functions operates.

Comment: Hi, it works! But this is confusing to me. Can you explain what are the function parameters that you used for "rowsBetween()"? Thanks for the answer btw!

Comment: See the docs below. The parameters specif the range of rows over which the max functions operates, in this case, it contains all the rows preceding and following the current row, i.e. all rows in the dataframe. https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.Window.rowsBetween

Answer (score 1):

There is one more alterenative to get **`max_timestamp`** is just **`grpupBy()`** the existing dataframe and use **`max()`** in order to get the **`max timestamp`** , take that in a **`variable`** and use as per your requirement

## Create the Df Here

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([(1,"2020-10-13"),(2,"2020-10-14"),(3,"2020-10-15")],[ "id","ts"])
df.show()
#df_max = df.groupBy("ts").agg(F.max("ts").alias("max_ts"))
df_max_var = df_max.collect()[0]['max_ts']
# Taking into a variable for future use
df = df.withColumn("dummy_col", F.lit(df_max_var))
df.show()
```

## Input

```
+---+----------+
| id|        ts|
+---+----------+
|  1|2020-10-13|
|  2|2020-10-14|
|  3|2020-10-15|
+---+----------+
```

## Output

```
+---+----------+----------+
| id|        ts| dummy_col|
+---+----------+----------+
|  1|2020-10-13|2020-10-15|
|  2|2020-10-14|2020-10-15|
|  3|2020-10-15|2020-10-15|
+---+----------+----------+
```